# How can I save a matrix in a txt file and then open it again as a matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I tried this:

```
  import numpy as np
  import os

  outdir= "directory"

  a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])

  os.chdir(outdir)

  np.savetxt("Image.bin", a)

  f = open("directory/Image.bin")
  m = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint16)
  print len(m)
  ma = np.array(np.reshape(m, (2,3)))

  print ma
```

But it returns this error message: "total size of new array must be unchanged"

I tried to change the dtype, but it dosen't work

Comment: Which line is actually failing?  The reshape() function looks suspicious.

Comment: Does it have to be text file?

Comment: Joel Cornett, no, just some file that i can open again. I used text file because it had worked until I tried to save it and open it again.

Comment: jeffrey_t_b, the fail line is the reshape function. But it works with files that I did not saved whith python.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `np.loadtxt`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Try:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
np.savetxt("Image.bin", a)
m = np.loadtxt("Image.bin")
```

`m` now contains the same array as `a`.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` has built in functions for saving and loading arrays as binary files.

```
numpy.save('data.npy', data)
```

will create the file (it will append npy if you don't), and

```
data = numpy.load('data.npy')
```

will load it from the file. This is both faster and more space efficient than saving them as text files.